# AdventOfCode 2019 day 6 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and currently trying to port my solutions for the 2019 installment of the coding challenge [AdventOfCode](https://adventofcode.com/) to Haskell. So, I would very much appreciate any suggestions how to make the code more readable and, in particular, more idiomatic.

This post shows my solution of [day 6](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/6) part 2, but also includes the function `totalDecendantCount` used to solve part 1. If you have not solved these problems and still intend to do so, stop reading immediately.

For both problems, you get a file with an *orbit specification* on each line of the form `A)B`, which tells you that `B` orbits `A`. This describes a tree of bodies orbiting each other with root `COM`.

In part 1, you have to compute a check sum. More precisely, you have to compute the sum of the number of direct and indirect orbits of each body, which is the same as the sum of the number of descendants of each body in the tree.

In part 2, which you cannot see if you have not finished part 1, you have to compute the minimal number of transfers between orbits from you (`YOU`) to Santa (`SAN`).

I have kept the entire solution for each part of each day in a single module with a single exported function that prints the solution. For day 6 part 2 it starts as follows.

```hs
module AdventOfCode20191206_2
    ( distanceToSanta
    ) where

import System.IO
import Data.List.Split
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Hashable
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as Map


distanceToSanta :: IO ()
distanceToSanta = do
    inputText <- readFile "Advent20191206_1_input.txt"
    let orbitList = (map orbit . lines) inputText
    let orbits = orbitMap $ catMaybes orbitList
    let pathToSanta = fromJust $ path orbits "COM" "YOU" "SAN"
    let requiredTransfers = length pathToSanta - 3
    print requiredTransfers
```

We subtract `3` from the length of the path because it consists of the bodies on the path and you only have to transfer from the body you already orbit to the body Santa orbits.

To store the tree, I use a `HashMap.Strict` and introduce the following type aliases and helper function to make things a bit more descriptive.

```hs
type OrbitSpecification = (String,String)
type ChildrenMap a = Map.HashMap a [a]

children :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> [a]
children childrenMap = fromMaybe [] . flip Map.lookup childrenMap
```

Next follow the functions I use to read in the tree.

```hs
orbit :: String -> Maybe OrbitSpecification
orbit str =
    case orbit_specification of
        [x,y] -> Just (x,y)
        _ -> Nothing
    where orbit_specification = splitOn ")" str

orbitMap :: [OrbitSpecification] -> ChildrenMap String
orbitMap = Map.fromListWith (++) . map (applyToSecondElement toSingleElementList)

applyToSecondElement :: (b -> c) -> (a,b) -> (a,c)
applyToSecondElement f (x,y) = (x, f y)

toSingleElementList :: a -> [a]
toSingleElementList x = [x]
```

To solve part 1, I introduce two general helper function to generate aggregates over children or over all descendents.

```hs
childrenAggregate :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ([a] -> b) -> ChildrenMap a -> a -> b
childrenAggregate aggregatorFnc childrenMap = aggregatorFnc . children childrenMap

decendantAggregate :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => (b -> b -> b) -> (ChildrenMap a -> a -> b) -> ChildrenMap a -> a -> b
decendantAggregate resultFoldFnc nodeFnc childrenMap node =
    foldl' resultFoldFnc nodeValue childResults
    where
        nodeValue = nodeFnc childrenMap node
        childFnc = decendantAggregate resultFoldFnc nodeFnc childrenMap
        childResults = map childFnc $ children childrenMap node
```

The `descendantAggragate` recursively applies a function `nodeFnc` to a node `node` and all its descendants and folds the results using some function `resultFoldFnc`. This allows to define the necessary functions to count the total number of descendants of a node as follows.

```hs
childrenCount :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> Int
childrenCount = childrenAggregate length

decendantCount ::  (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> Int
decendantCount = decendantAggregate (+) childrenCount

totalDecendantCount :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> Int
totalDecendantCount = decendantAggregate (+) decendantCount
```

For part 2, we use that between two points in a tree, there is exactly one path (without repetition). First, we define a function to get a path from the root of a (sub)tree to the destination, provided it exists.

```hs
pathFromRoot :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> a -> Maybe [a]
pathFromRoot childrenMap root destination
    | destination == root = Just [root]
    | null childPaths = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just $ root:(head childPaths)
    where
        rootChildren = children childrenMap root
        pathFromNewRoot newRoot = pathFromRoot childrenMap newRoot destination
        childPaths = mapMaybe pathFromNewRoot rootChildren
```

This function only finds paths down from the root of a (sub)tree. General paths come in three variations: path from the root of a (sub)tree, the inverse of such a path or the concatenation of a path to the root of a subtree and one from that root to the end point. Thus, we get the path as follows.

```hs
path :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> a -> a -> Maybe [a]
path childrenMap root start end =
    let maybeStartEndPath = pathFromRoot childrenMap start end
    in if isJust maybeStartEndPath
        then maybeStartEndPath
        else let maybeEndStartPath = pathFromRoot childrenMap end start
                in case maybeEndStartPath of
                    Just endStartPath -> Just $ reverse endStartPath
                    Nothing -> let
                        rootPathToStart = pathFromRoot childrenMap root start
                        rootPathToEnd = pathFromRoot childrenMap root end
                        in if isNothing rootPathToStart || isNothing rootPathToEnd
                            then Nothing
                            else connectedPath (fromJust rootPathToStart) (fromJust rootPathToEnd)
```

To connect the paths in the last alternative, we follow both paths from the root to the last common point and then build it by concatenation the reverse of the path to the start with the path to the destination.

```hs
connectedPath :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
connectedPath rootToStart rootToEnd =
    case pathPieces of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just (middle, middleToStart, middleToEnd) ->
            Just $ (reverse middleToStart) ++ [middle] ++ middleToEnd
    where pathPieces = distinctPathPieces rootToStart rootToEnd

distinctPathPieces :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe (a, [a], [a])
distinctPathPieces [x] [y] = if x == y then Just (x, [], []) else Nothing
distinctPathPieces (x1:y1:z1) (x2:y2:z2)
  | x1 /= x2 = Nothing
  | y1 /= y2 = Just (x1, y1:z1, y2:z2)
  | otherwise = distinctPathPieces (y1:z1) (y2:z2)
distinctPathPieces _ _ = Nothing
```

This solution heavily depends on the input describing a tree. In case a DAG is provided, a result will be produced that is not necessary correct. For `totalDescendantCount`, nodes after joining branches will be counted multiple times and `path` will find a path, but not nescesarily the shortest one. If there are cycles in the graph provided, the recursions in the functions will not terminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simplification

In `path`, notice how the code gets more nested as you try each possible path (either from start to end, or end to start, or from end to root and root to start). You can use the Alternative instance for `Maybe` to simplify this code:

```hs
let maybeStartEndPath = pathFromRoot childrenMap start end
    maybeEndStartPath = pathFromRoot childrenMap end start
    maybeRootPath = [...] -- see below
in 
      maybeStartEndPath
  <|> fmap reverse maybeEndStartPath
  <|> maybeRootPath
```

This code will try `maybeStartEndPath` first. If it returns `Nothing`, it will move on to the next option and so on.

For your final case (which I've named `maybeRootPath`), you do the following check:

```hs
if isNothing rootPathToStart || isNothing rootPathToEnd
    then Nothing
    else connectedPath (fromJust rootPathToStart) (fromJust rootPathToEnd)
```

This is more consicely done with `liftA2` from `Control.Applicative`. `liftA2` lifts a binary function into an applicative context:

```
λ :set -XTypeApplications
λ :t liftA2 @Maybe
liftA2 @Maybe :: (a -> b -> c) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c)
```

Then, if either argument is `Nothing`, the function will return `Nothing` without having to pattern match. So we can fill in `maybeRootPath` above with

```hs
        maybeRootPath = join $ liftA2 connectedPath rootPathToStart rootPathToEnd
          where
            rootPathToStart = pathFromRoot childrenMap root start
            rootPathToEnd = pathFromRoot childrenMap root end
```

The `join` is needed because `connectedPath` returns a `Maybe` already, and we've lifted it into `Maybe`, which leaves us with a return value of `Maybe (Maybe [a])`. `join` flattens nested monads, bringing us back to `Maybe [a]`

---

### Minor points

Your function `applyToSecondElement` is `second` from `Control.Arrow`

```
λ :t second @(->)
second @(->) :: (b -> c) -> (d, b) -> (d, c)
```

---

`toSingleElementList` can also be written as `(:[])` or `return`

So `orbitMap` can be written

```hs
orbitMap = Map.fromListWith (++) . map (second (:[]))
```

To your credit, your naming made both of these functions clear anyway, but it's more recognizable if you use functions that already exist.

---

### Algorithm

I was going to suggest keeping each edge bidirectional instead of one-directional, so that you can directly check for a path from start to end instead of checking 3 cases. After reviewing the code, I think your approach is better from a functional perspective because it eliminates the need for you to check for cycles and keep a set as you search the graph. Good work.

---

### Revised Code

```hs
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Arrow
import System.IO
import Data.List.Split
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Hashable
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as Map


main :: IO ()
main = do
    inputText <- readFile "Advent20191206_1_input.txt"
    let orbitList = catMaybes $ (map orbit . lines) inputText
    let orbits = orbitMap orbitList
    let pathToSanta = fromJust $ path orbits "COM" "YOU" "SAN"
    let requiredTransfers = length pathToSanta - 3
    print requiredTransfers

type OrbitSpecification = (String,String)
type ChildrenMap a = Map.HashMap a [a]

children :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> [a]
children childrenMap = fromMaybe [] . flip Map.lookup childrenMap

orbit :: String -> Maybe OrbitSpecification
orbit str =
    case orbit_specification of
        [x,y] -> Just (x, y)
        _ -> Nothing
    where orbit_specification = splitOn ")" str

orbitMap :: [OrbitSpecification] -> ChildrenMap String
orbitMap = Map.fromListWith (++) . map (second (:[]))

childrenAggregate :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ([a] -> b) -> ChildrenMap a -> a -> b
childrenAggregate aggregatorFnc childrenMap = aggregatorFnc . children childrenMap

decendantAggregate :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => (b -> b -> b) -> (ChildrenMap a -> a -> b) -> ChildrenMap a -> a -> b
decendantAggregate resultFoldFnc nodeFnc childrenMap node =
    foldl' resultFoldFnc nodeValue childResults
    where
        nodeValue = nodeFnc childrenMap node
        childFnc = decendantAggregate resultFoldFnc nodeFnc childrenMap
        childResults = map childFnc $ children childrenMap node

childrenCount :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> Int
childrenCount = childrenAggregate length

decendantCount ::  (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> Int
decendantCount = decendantAggregate (+) childrenCount

totalDecendantCount :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> Int
totalDecendantCount = decendantAggregate (+) decendantCount

pathFromRoot :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> a -> Maybe [a]
pathFromRoot childrenMap root destination
    | destination == root = Just [root]
    | null childPaths = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just $ root:(head childPaths)
    where
        rootChildren = children childrenMap root
        pathFromNewRoot newRoot = pathFromRoot childrenMap newRoot destination
        childPaths = mapMaybe pathFromNewRoot rootChildren

path :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => ChildrenMap a -> a -> a -> a -> Maybe [a]
path childrenMap root start end =
    let maybeStartEndPath = pathFromRoot childrenMap start end
        maybeEndStartPath = pathFromRoot childrenMap end start

        maybeRootPath = join $ liftA2 connectedPath rootPathToStart rootPathToEnd
          where
            rootPathToStart = pathFromRoot childrenMap root start
            rootPathToEnd = pathFromRoot childrenMap root end
    in
          maybeStartEndPath
      <|> fmap reverse maybeEndStartPath
      <|> maybeRootPath

connectedPath :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
connectedPath rootToStart rootToEnd =
    case pathPieces of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just (middle, middleToStart, middleToEnd) ->
            Just $ (reverse middleToStart) ++ [middle] ++ middleToEnd
    where pathPieces = distinctPathPieces rootToStart rootToEnd

distinctPathPieces :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe (a, [a], [a])
distinctPathPieces [x] [y] = if x == y then Just (x, [], []) else Nothing
distinctPathPieces (x1:y1:z1) (x2:y2:z2)
  | x1 /= x2 = Nothing
  | y1 /= y2 = Just (x1, y1:z1, y2:z2)
  | otherwise = distinctPathPieces (y1:z1) (y2:z2)
distinctPathPieces _ _ = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I already had the feeling that there had to be some function to apply a function to the second element, but did not know `Arrow`. I will need some time to look things up in order to fully understand your simplifications. But now I know some directions to look into to improve my Haskell.