# Advent of Code 2019: Day 6 (with Trees)

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell

I've been going through some 2019 AoC challenges and decided to solve [Day 6](https://adventofcode.com/2019/day/6) in Haskell with the help of `Data.Tree`.

In summary, the puzzle provides a list of orbits (edges) as input, resembling:

```
COM)B
B)C
C)D
D)E
E)F
B)G
G)H
D)I
E)J
J)K
K)L
K)YOU
I)SAN
```

where `COM` is supposedly the centre of all orbits (i.e. the root). We are tasked with parsing this and...

- for Part 1: Find the **total** number of *direct* and *indirect orbits*. In the example,

  - `B` directly orbits `COM`
  - `C` directly orbits `B` (hence, indirectly orbiting `COM`)
  - `D` directly orbits `C` (hence, indirectly orbiting `B` *and* `COM`)
  - and so on...
- for Part 2: Find the *minimum number of orbital transfers*. Basically, the number of traversals needed to get from the orbit of `YOU` to the orbit of `SAN`. In the example, the traversals are `K -> J -> E -> D -> I`. Hence, the minimum number of transfers is **`4`**.

Here is my solution to both parts:

```hs
import Data.Tree

type Satellite = String
type STree = Tree Satellite
type Orbit = (Satellite, Satellite)

--  Part 1
main :: IO ()
main = interact $ show . countOrbits . fromOrbits . map parseOrbit . lines

--  Part 2
-- main :: IO ()
-- main = interact $ show . findMinimumTransfers "YOU" "SAN" . fromOrbits . map parseOrbit . lines

parseOrbit :: String -> Orbit
parseOrbit s = (takeWhile (/= ')') s, tail $ dropWhile (/= ')') s)

fromOrbits :: [Orbit] -> STree
fromOrbits orbits = construct "COM"
    where construct :: Satellite -> STree
          construct root = Node { rootLabel = root, subForest = map construct $ children root }

          children :: Satellite -> [Satellite]
          children sat = map snd $ filter ((== sat) . fst) orbits

countOrbits :: STree -> Integer
countOrbits = countOrbitsImpl 0
    where countOrbitsImpl :: Integer -> STree -> Integer
          countOrbitsImpl depth (Node rootLabel subForest)
                | length subForest == 0 = depth
                | otherwise = depth + (sum $ map (countOrbitsImpl (depth + 1)) subForest)

-- finds the minimum number of orbital transfers required between two targets
findMinimumTransfers :: Satellite -> Satellite -> STree -> Int
findMinimumTransfers tar tar' = findImpl 0
    where -- find the common node where targets are (possibly indirect) children
          findImpl :: Int -> STree -> Int
          findImpl depth (Node rootLabel subForest)
                | rootLabel == tar || rootLabel == tar' = depth - 1
                | length subForest == 0 = 0
                | otherwise = 
                    let childResults = filter (/= 0) $ map (findImpl (depth + 1)) subForest
                    in  if length childResults == 2
                        then sum childResults - (depth * length childResults)   --  found common node
                        else sum childResults   --  propagate results
```

I'm itching for feedback on the recursion. I use it mainly to keep track of a node's `depth` and later return it as part of the result... but is there a "better" way to write this? Maybe with folds or applicatives?

I *did* think about keeping depth as part of a node's data (so that we might have `type STree = Tree (Satellite, Int)`), then maybe we could fold over that, but I didn't want to "bloat" the structure with redundant information.

Other feedback is also welcome. Thanks!

<sub>N.B. this is not a duplicate of [AdventOfCode 2019 day 6 in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234762/adventofcode-2019-day-6-in-haskell) as the implementation is different.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `break` and `span`

When we try to split a string in Haskell, we're a little bit out of luck if we only use the trusty `Prelude` and `base`. Handy functions like `split` or `splitOn`  are in the adaptly named `split` package, and parser combinators are completely other beasts and an oribtal (heh) laser cannon on this problem.

However, there are two functions that provide almost exactly what `parseOrbit` is trying to achieve: splitting a string on a single character:

```
span, break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
span  f xs = (takeWhile f xs, dropWhile f xs)
break f xs = span (not . f)
```

We can simplify `parseOrbit` therefore to

```
parseOrbit :: String -> Orbit
parseOrbit s = let (a, _:b) = break (==')') s in (a, b)
```

However, you seem to prefer `where`, so let's use a `where` clause instead:

```
parseOrbit :: String -> Orbit
parseOrbit s = (a, b)
    where (a, _:b) = break (==')') s
```

## Type signatures in where clauses

As we have seen above, `(a, _:b)` had no type signature. Type signatures in `where` clasues are usually omitted. There is some [controversy about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609936/why-is-it-so-uncommon-to-use-type-signatures-in-where-clauses), however there are some things to keep in mind:

- GHC never warns about missing type signatures in `where` clauses
- functions with type parameters cannot have a type without `ScopedTypeSignatures` (see [this SO question for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400105/specifying-a-function-type-signature-in-a-where-clause))
- a change in the top level type signature might need a lot of changes in `where` clauses
- if a function is complex enough to need a type, it might be reasonable to promote it into a top-level function. That way it can also be tested.

I personally therefore omit type signatures in `where` clauses (`ST` shenengians aside).

Answer (score 2):

## `countOrbits`

Let's take a look at what your algorithm is doing. Suppose you are at a root node `r` with subtree `s` at depth `d0`. You return the sum of `d0` and all of the depths of the nodes in `s`.

### Nitpicks

`sum [] = 0`, so you could just write `countOrbitsImpl` as its `otherwise` clause. Not checking the `length` also makes your code slightly faster. `length` is O(n) in the list it acts on. So if `length subForest /= 0`, you'll iterate over the whole subforest before knowing that.

In this case, you can eliminate the unnecessary guard, but where it is necessary to check the subforest, you should prefer `null subForest` to `length subForest == 0` because of the aforementioned reason.

You should either put an `_` in front of a variable you don't use (`_rootLabel`) or replace the variable name with an `_`. Otherwise, if you turn on `-Wall` you'll get a warning about an unused variable.

### Rewriting

You asked about an alternative to your recursive function using a fold or applicative. Here's a way to restate your algorithm: imagine that each node in the tree had a depth associated with it. You want the sum of that.

So instead of recursing over the tree, you can make a tree of depths and then sum that tree. We'll get to how you can sum it in a moment, but let's first make that tree.

```hs
mkDepthTree :: Integer -> STree -> Tree Integer
mkDepthTree depth (Node _ subForest) = Node depth (map (mkDepthTree (depth+1)) subForest)
```

This doesn't look very different from `countOrbitsImpl`, it just isn't adding anything up.

Once we have the tree of depths, we want to sum it. Fortunately, `Tree` has a [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) instance. Which means it's a valid input to `sum`. Thus, you can write `countOrbits` as

```hs
countOrbits :: STree -> Integer
countOrbits = sum . mkDepthTree 0
    where mkDepthTree depth (Node _ subForest) = Node depth (map (mkDepthTree (depth+1)) subForest)
```

I used your indentation, although I personally prefer using 2 spaces, putting a newline after `where` and then indenting the line after by 2 more.

### Which to prefer?

In a function that is this simple, I wouldn't say either version is necessarily better. Converting to a tree of depths then summing feels more elegant (it can almost be written as a `foldMap` if you didn't need the depth information), but it's also slightly harder to understand. Recursing directly is slightly clunkier, but IMO easier to understand.

So it's your decision.

## More to come?

It got kind of late so I'm stopping this review. I'll see if I can edit in a review of `findMinimumTransfers` later.